# Having OSGi services use latest version of bundle, even if multiple bundle versions are installed

Tags: service, osgi, version

I'm facing an OSGi problem, and I'm not sufficiently well versed in OSGi details to figure out a way forward.

My problem is this:

- I have a service, which lives behind a well-defined interface, and periodically emits a file in a particular location. This is controlled by the config admin (via a config file in Karaf)
- Some components provide this service to others via a Karaf feature file, bundling my service in a particular version (1.X.0)
- Other components provide this service in a newer version (1.Y.0, where Y > X), either via another feature file, or just by adding it to their kar file.

As these are just minor version changes, the consuming services don't really care which service they talk to (the API is the same).

My problem is that both of these bundles are Active in karaf, and there is a race condition as to who gets to overwrite who's output file.
I tried making the `@Component` into a Singleton (using `scope = ServiceScope.SINGLETON`), and while this might solve the case of every service consumer using the same implementation, the issue of file overwriting persists, as both services are Active.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to tell OSGi to "don't bother with the older versions, the new version (which is the same major as the others) are fine for all of the consumers (who use the default of `[1.X,2[`)

As the config file is akin to an "API" for enabling my service I would like to avoid having multiple config files for the different versions.

If possible, I would like to keep the version location logic outside of my service. I guess in theory, the service could listen for other versions of bundles providing the same service interface, and take appropriate action - but this seems very cumbersome to me. Surely there is a better way, which has less impact on the business logic code (i.e. my service)?

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is of course, why bother with the old bundle? Just uninstall it?

Anyway, the usual answer is then: I can't for some reason. Some solutions in preferred (my) order:

1. Remove older bundle
2. Make your components `require` a configuration and configure the appropriate component, the other one  won't run. This is basically the pattern that gave us the Configurator specification. This is actually a **really** good solution  that I use everywhere. It allows the application to be configured in fine detail.
3. Just solve the configuration file conflict in the bundles.
4. Use startlevels to never start the older bundle. A bit of a hack.
5. Register a service property with the service and let the references  filter on that property. Rabbit hole.
6. Use Service Hooks to filter out the old service. This introduces ordering since the  service hook must be registered before anyone using it. So I tend to shy away from it. Here is an [implementation](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/220d41232ca106dbbcd7e0cfc4365aaa9c32db69/biz.aQute.launchpad/src/aQute/launchpad/Launchpad.java#L678)

This is imho a typical use case that, in retrospect, made the system *much* more complicated than expected. One hack like this does not seem to be too bad but these hacks tend to multiply like rabbits. OSGi is about clean modules communicating with well defined services. Your description seems you're there but then not correctly solving the problem will lead you down the path to the big ball of mud again :-(

Answer (score 1):

For Apache Karaf there is a special way to implement the first solution from Peter (Remove older bundle).

Set `dependency=true` in the feature file for the bundle that provides the service.
This way Apache Karaf will automatically install the best bundle for the requirements of your other bundles. In this case it should only install the providing bundle with the highest minor version number.